Google Maps init with custom markers
The following init function throws a 'Cannot set properties of undefined' this line: (markers[markerItem.id] = marker) :
       function initMap() {
            var marker = null;
            var map_markers = map_settings.marker;
            //console.log('map_markers.length '+map_markers.length); 
            //console.log('map_settings.start_lat '+map_settings.start_lng);
            if(map_markers.length > 0) var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var mylat = map_settings.start_lat;
            var mylong = map_settings.start_lng;
            var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylong), zoom: 6, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            (map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)),
                map_markers.length > 0 &&
                    map_markers.forEach(function(markerItem) {
                        var marker_icon = "";        
                        var marker = "";
                        markerItem.icon && (marker_icon = markerItem.icon);
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerItem.lat, markerItem.lng), map: map, title: markerItem.title, infoWindow: void 0 }),
                            icon = { url: markerItem.icon }, 
                            image_icon = new Image();
                        console.log('marker '+ marker );
                        if (
                            ((image_icon.src = markerItem.icon),
                            (image_icon.onload = function () {
                                marker.setIcon(icon);
                            }),
                            (image_icon.onerror = function () {
                                marker.setIcon(null);
                            }),
                           (marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: markerItem.info, maxWidth: 200 })),
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                                markers.forEach(function (item) {
                                    item.infoWindow && item.infoWindow.close();
                                }),
                                    this.infoWindow && this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
                            }),
                            (markers[markerItem.id] = marker),
                            bounds.extend(marker.position),
                            bounds.getNorthEast().equals(bounds.getSouthWest()))
                        ) {
                            var extendPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + 0.01, bounds.getNorthEast().lng() + 0.01),
                                extendPoint2 = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - 0.01, bounds.getNorthEast().lng() - 0.01);
                            bounds.extend(extendPoint1), bounds.extend(extendPoint2);
                        }
                    }),
                map_markers.length > 0 && map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }


I got a simular code running in an older project ... what do I oversee here?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear to me where markers is defined. I see map_markers and I see marker, but I do not see markers.

Gzuz! Added 'var markers = [];' and there we go. Thank you very much for taking the time!
